# Running tests in specific category in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, testing, automated-tests

In a project using official **Microsoft unit test framework** I can put test in *categories* however I can't run these categories from the test explorer in Visual Studio.

I specifically want to set one category to Run after build (not on a build server via CI but locally) because I might have specific test I do not want to run that often.

Is there any way to do this or is the testing aspect from within Visual Studio so limited?

Answer (score 5):

When running tests from the test explorer window, you can filter by "Trait".

Entering `Trait:"Important"` into the search bar will select only tests marked with `[TestCategory("Important")]`.

To exclude certain tests prefix with '-' e.g. `-Trait:"Slow"`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using vstest (part of Visual Studio), either via CI (Jenkins, etc.), a Windows Scheduled Task, launched batch file, etc.

Simply call something like:
`Vstest.console.exe myTestProject.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory=Nightly`

Please reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx

Comment: I was thinking about something from within Visual Studio, but I guess I could add this to the build events in properties right?